# Are the photographs of battered Indian soldiers released on Chinese social media authentic?

Tags: china, india

A while ago two Pakistani newspapers released the news that Chinese social media released the following photos of battered Indian soldiers in the Chinese hands which India never officially admitted.

- [Indians furious over release of bruised soldiers' pictures by China](https://tribune.com.pk/story/2324161/indians-furious-over-release-of-bruised-soldiers-pictures-by-china)
- [India furious over pictures of soldiers beaten by PLA](https://dailytimes.com.pk/827794/india-furious-over-pictures-of-soldiers-beaten-by-pla/)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

.

Indian military experts said that those photos are fake implying that they are staged (i.e., cinematically directed and shot):

[image]

By the way, the Tweet of Maj. Gen. Harsha Kakar says that:

> Indian soldiers do not have long hair.

This is actually a lie as **Sikh** soldiers have long hair. Besides, allegedly, these Indian soldiers were in Chinese custody for months.

.

**Are the photographs of battered Indian soldiers released on Chinese social media authentic?**

Comment: First question, is the original Chinese twitter post available directly and does it correspond to an actual official state media outlet?

Comment: @quarague, Yes. Yes. 
 https://twitter.com/shen_shiwei/status/1457175215432216576